# What kind of bird is this greyish small chicken sized one I found in the Uintas?

Tags: united-states, bird-identification

On my hike through the Uinta mountains, I came across this greyish bird and her 3-4 chicks. The timelapse I took of the birds can be seen [here](https://youtu.be/HgmPM0vjf2o?t=527).

[image]

It looks like some sort of grouse, does anybody know what kind of bird this is?

Comment: First glance (ok second 'cause it is hard to see...) I'd sa a female grouse.

Comment: Yep - that is definitely grouse shaped

Comment: It IS a grouse, but what variety is hard to say.  Do you have a good pic with the chicks for the contest?